# Pika crashes with no obvious reason

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a problem. My pika client permanently crashes with an error message.

This is what happens:

1. RabbitMQ is running and the producer already pushed messages into the queue
2. I start my python script and it processes all the packages that are buffered in the queue
3. My script periodically throws the exeption: ConnectionClosed, however I never close anything anywhere

This is my code:

```
import pika
import traceback

class RPCServer(object):


    def __init__(self, callback, cfg):
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.callback = callback
        self.credentials = None
        self.parameters = None
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None
        self.counter = 0
        self.initalize_me()


    def initalize_me(self):
        self.credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.cfg.USER, self.cfg.PASSWORD)
        self.parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=self.cfg.AMQP_HOST, credentials=self.credentials)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(self.parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME, type="direct")
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME)
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange=self.cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME, queue=self.cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME, routing_key=self.cfg.RPC_ROUTING_KEY)
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.rpc_callback, queue=self.cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME)
        print "init= " + str(self.cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME) + " -> " + str(self.cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME) + " -> " + str(self.cfg.RPC_ROUTING_KEY)


    def start_rpc_server(self):
        print "Server: Start listening for RPC requests..."
        try:
            self.channel.start_consuming()
        except:
            print "Exception: " + str(traceback.format_exc())
            self.initalize_me()
            self.start_rpc_server()


    def rpc_callback(self, ch, method, props, body):
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter == 100:
            print "100 package processed..."
            self.counter = 0
        result = self.callback(body)
        properties = pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=props.correlation_id)
        ch.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=props.reply_to, properties=properties, body=result)
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

And this is the output when I run it:

```
python RunPacer.py 
Initialize Configuration
Start Pacer
100 package processed...
100 package processed...
init= pacing_exchange_debug -> pacing_queue_debug -> pacing_routing_key_debug
Server: Start listening for RPC requests...
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Tom/Pacer/amqp/RPCServer.py", line 46, in start_rpc_server
    self.channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 955, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 243, in process_data_events
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
ConnectionClosed

100 package processed...
100 package processed...
init= pacing_exchange_debug -> pacing_queue_debug -> pacing_routing_key_debug
Server: Start listening for RPC requests...
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Tom/Pacer/amqp/RPCServer.py", line 46, in start_rpc_server
    self.channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 955, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 243, in process_data_events
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
ConnectionClosed

init= pacing_exchange_debug -> pacing_queue_debug -> pacing_routing_key_debug
Server: Start listening for RPC requests...
100 package processed...
100 package processed...
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Tom/Pacer/amqp/RPCServer.py", line 46, in start_rpc_server
    self.channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 955, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 243, in process_data_events
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
ConnectionClosed
```

Sorry, my description is very unprecise, however, this is due to that I have absolutely no idea why my script crashes. So any, really any, advise would be helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: Error logs of rabbitmq added:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 4-Dec-2014::12:55:42 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.8947.0> (183.13.20.123:61598 -> 183.13.20.123:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Dec-2014::12:55:42 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.8947.0> (183.13.20.123:61598 -> 183.13.20.123:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'username', state: running), channel 1:
{amqp_error,unexpected_frame,
            "expected content body, got non content body frame instead",
            'basic.publish'}

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Dec-2014::12:55:43 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.8947.0> (183.13.20.123:61598 -> 183.13.20.123:5672)
```

Additionally: I have a Java program working on the same queue (actually a copy of the python script in java) which runs without any problems.

Comment: Is the any indication of a problem in the RabbitMQ logs?

Comment: Does your Java program gracefully try to reconnect on connection errors?  Any other logs (dmesg/rabbitmq/etc) have events at the time of disconnect?

Comment: No, my Java program does not try to reconnect. I did not find any other issues in any log files.

Comment: Are your Java and Python programs on the same server? edit: How often is this crashing?

Comment: Yes, they run on the same machine. I ran them simultaneously and each one without the other. I have the feeling that this is an unsolved bug in pika (see here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/349 )

Comment: @toom I upvoted your answer and you should accept your own answer.  It's worth noting for future readers though that librabbitmq (as of today) does not support Python 3, which should be considered a dealbreaker for new applications.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a bug in Pika (see here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/349). Since this issue has not been fixed now for over a year (bug report 12/2013 this post: 12/2014) I'm not gonna rely on pika any longer.

However, a great (and fast) alternative (which results in even less code) is librabbitmq: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/librabbitmq

Here is example code that implements a RPC call with librabbitmq:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from librabbitmq import Connection
import uuid

class RPCClient(object):

    def __init__(self, cfg):
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.connection = Connection(host=cfg.AMQP_HOST, userid=cfg.USER, password=cfg.PASSWORD)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
        self.callback_queue = result.queue
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = None
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback_queue, callback=self.process_response)


    def process_response(self, msg):
        if self.corr_id == msg.properties['correlation_id']:
            self.response = str(msg.body)


    def rpc_call(self, msg):
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        props = {'reply_to' : str(self.callback_queue), 'correlation_id' : str(self.corr_id)}

        self.channel.basic_publish(msg, exchange=self.cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME,
                                   routing_key=self.cfg.RPC_ROUTING_KEY, **props)
        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.drain_events()
        return str(self.response)
```

And the corresponding RPCServer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from librabbitmq import Connection

class RPCServer(object):

    def __init__(self, callback, cfg):
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.callback = callback
        self.connection = Connection(host=cfg.AMQP_HOST, userid=cfg.USER, password=cfg.PASSWORD)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct")
        self.channel.queue_declare(cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME)
        self.channel.queue_bind(cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME, cfg.RPC_EXCHANGE_NAME, cfg.RPC_ROUTING_KEY)
        self.channel.basic_consume(cfg.RPC_QUEUE_NAME, callback=self.rpc_callback)


    def start_rpc_server(self):
        while True: self.connection.drain_events()


    def rpc_callback(self, msg):
        resp = self.callback(msg.body)
        self.channel.basic_publish(resp, exchange="", routing_key=msg.properties['reply_to'], **msg.properties)
        self.channel.basic_ack(msg.delivery_info['delivery_tag'])
```